# Placing Google Analytics code in Wordpress specific page

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

I'm trying to get Google Analytics Code to work on the thank-you page after customer has filled in the contact form and I've tried putting it in the thank-you page which is in the pages under admin in Wordpress backend using HTML tab but it seems to generate unnecessary p and br tags in between codes especially before closing  tag. I'm not sure whether that is causing the issue or not.
Is there a way we can do this for just one page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100 % sure whether it's possible at all to insert javascript with the tinyMCE Editor of Wordpress.

If that's true, then you can try the following:

1. Get the posts' ID: Look at the linking in your admin menu when you are in the view where you can see all your posts, e.g.

   http://www.your-url.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=796&action=edit

   796 would be your ID here.
2. Enter the following in your header.php of your wordpress theme (to find at /wp-content/themes/theme-name):

.

```
  <?php if (is_page(796)) { ?>   
   //YOUR ANALYTICS CODE IN HERE
  <?php } ?>
```

Replace 796 with your ID here, and put your analytics code in between the PHP code.

Comment: I don't want to add in header.php as it will be for all pages of the site and also your method of getting post id is useless when you have permalinks changed to seo friendly it's better to check with $post->ID or in the MySql database. Please can I please have decent answers? I appreciate your efforts but we need accurate information here in Stackoverflow

Comment: OK you are right I will try is_page with php tags. I'm not sure why I didn't try in the first place. Thank you!

Comment: Permalinks neither influence the links in the adminmenu, nor do they change the posts unique ID! Finally, as I said, it's propably not possible to add javascript in the wordpress Editor. But it's no problem, the php code I submitted will work so the analytics code will only be executed when the page with the given ID is displayed!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to add it using the "Visual" view, which formats whatever you put in into paragraphs, etc.

Try switching to "HTML" view (the tab is at the top right of the input box) and add it there - hopefully that should allow you to add it without converting it!

**Edit:** As per my comments below, I made a mistake - it seems even the HTML tab adds some degree of formatting.

In this case, you may find some use with this plugin:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/raw-html/

This allows you to displable to auto formatting on a per-post basis.  So on that specific page you could turn off the autoformatting simply to allow you to add that Analytics snippet.

The only other way I can think off offhand would be to write a custom page_template just for that thankyou page and add it to there.  Instructions are here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates

Comment: Oops - realised I misread.  Is it possible you're adding it to the HTML tab, then switching back to Visual and saving it again?  It could be the conversion is happening then.

Comment: No I'm saving as HTML without switching to the Visual view. Please read before answering.

Comment: I did. Please read comments before responding.  ;-)   So have you switched back to Visual view *at all* since adding the analytics code?  HTML view should be just that - it doesn't add any auto formatting at all.

Comment: I've done a bit of googling and it seems WordPress *does* add <p> tags, even in HTML mode. Crazy - in 4 years WP coding I've never spotted this.  One option is to look at the wpautop plugin, which removes this formatting... http://urbangiraffe.com/plugins/disable-wpautop/