# Google Analytics for Individual WordPress Pages

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, google-analytics

I am trying to add google analytics to a website. The only issue is, the website has a bunch of different pages, and someone requested that analytics be added to only certain webpages, instead of the whole website. I don't want to edit the theme, at all, I just want to be able to add the script to an individual page...

When adding the script into the normal webpage in wordpress, (what should be the insides of the  section), it auto removes the script tags, and just puts in the code.

When adding the script as a text widget to the page, it does the same thing as above...removes the script tags when I save the widget, while this may work, I would like to have some reassurance that it does, or a better method that doesn't seem as much of a work around.

If I am unclear, please let me know and I can clarify more, hopefully someone has an answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7567391/placing-google-analytics-code-in-wordpress-specific-page

Comment: That would work, but I do not want to add anything to the header...

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  Why not just add GA and then set up a filter for the pages you don't want to track?

Comment: I agree with @Brad. (If there is no tracking on a session's landingpage it is a mess, so it is better to filter only what you need to.) Another option is to add tag manager to every page and then restrict the URLs that add the GA tag. Then it is globally manageable as people realize they need more and more things tracked.

Comment: Hm ok. What you guys are saying makes complete sense. I will have to do some more research into how to do so, I am fairly restricted with access to the page and this is the first time I am setting up google analytics. I appreciate all of the help.

Comment: @PatrickZawadzki The filtering is done in the admin panel for Google Analytics.

Comment: Use Google Tag Manager and set the rules to only fire tags on exact urls.